# How to avoid boxplot categories being too close to each other?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

How to avoid boxplot categories being too close to each other? See the picture I uploaded, I can't even distinguish the words.

```
# Residual vs Category
census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.boxplot(column='residual',by='CNMCRGNNM')
plt.savefig('../output/linear_model/residual_vs_region.png')
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set the x_ticks more apart with plt.axis[,500,500,-200,200] --> try different values. Respectively wide the figsize. If you load up your code from which you create the plot I will try to show it

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the box plot axis labels by passing `rot=90` to `boxplot()`:

```
census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.boxplot(column='residual',by='CNMCRGNNM', rot=90)
```